# avoid duplication using placeholder selectors in Sass 3.2

Tags: sass

The problem is that my Sass code is generating duplicate declarations in the compiled CSS file.
My Sass code is organized in multiple partials, and I @import them into a final screen.scss file

I have a `_placeholders.scss` which contains `%alignright` and `%alignleft`. 
I have a `_content.scss` file which uses these, so I `@import "_placeholder.scss"` at the top of that file and I do the same in _footer.scss. So I guess `@import "_placeholders.scss"` in 2 places is causing the duplication?

If I just `@import "_placeholders.scss"` at the beginning of `screen.scss` to make them globally accessible, then it messes with the order of the CSS declarations.
The first CSS selector to use a placeholder selector will be inserted at the order where I `@import "_placeholders.scss"`, instead of where I `@import "_conntent.scss"`.

For example, in screen.scss:

```
@import "placeholders";
@import "reset";
@import "typography"
@import "content" // uses placeholder %alignleft
@import "footer" // uses placeholder alignleft
```

Generated CSS:

```
/* Content styles that use placeholders */
/* reset styles */
/* typography styles  */
/* expected order of content styles  */
/* footer styles  */
```

How do I avoid duplication and get the styles to be output in the correct place in the compiled CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This is a place where you'd need to `@include` a `@mixin` rather than `@extending` a placeholder.

```
// in _placeholders.scss

@mixin alignleft {
    text-align: left;
}

// in _content.scss

div.whatever {
    @include alignleft;
}

// in _footer.scss

div.whatever-footer {
    @include alignleft;
}
```